# Error al compilar, ayuda con POO en C++

Tags: c++, poo

Estoy aprendiendo programación POO y tengo un pequeño error al intentar hacer mi primer "objeto". Me da este error.

> C:\Users\Manflack\AppData\Local\Temp\ccf4P5ij.o    poo3.cpp:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `Persona::Persona(int, int, int)'

Este es mi código:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Persona{
private:
int alt,pe,prommd; //alto peso promediomes
public:
Persona(int,int,int);
void asignAlt(int,int);
void cPe(int,int,int);
void promm(int);
void prnt();
};

void Persona::asignAlt(int mAlt,int pAlt){
alt=(mAlt+pAlt)/2; }
void Persona::cPe(int mPe,int pPe,int cd){
pe=((mPe+pPe)/2)+cd/100; }
void Persona::promm(int prom){
prommd=prom/30; }
void Persona::prnt(){
cout<<"La altura de la persona es de: "<<alt<<"\nSu peso es de: "<<pe<<"\nY su ingreso diario es de: "<<prommd; }

main(){
int t1,t2,t3;
cout<<"Ingrese la altura de su madre y su padre: ";
cin>>t1>>t2;
Persona Mariano(t1,t2,t3);
cout<<"Ingrese el peso de su madre, su padre y cuantas calorias consume al dia: ";
cin>>t1>>t2>>t3;
Mariano.cPe(t1,t2,t3);
cout<<"Ingrese su sueldo promedio al mes: "<<endl;
cin>>t1;
Mariano.promm(t1);
Mariano.prnt();

cin.get();
return 0; }
```

Comment: Puede que [esta guía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65557/simbolo-externo-sin-resolver-qu%c3%a9-he-hecho-mal) te ayude a entender el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te está indicando claramente el error:

> ```
> undefined reference to Persona::Persona(int, int, int)
> ```

Esa línea viene a decir: "*No encuentro la **definición** de la función `Persona` con tres parámetros `int` en el contexto de `Persona::`*.

#### Problema

Esto puede suceder por dos motivos:

1. La función `Persona::Persona(int, int, int)` está declarada pero no está definida. En otras palabras, la función existe pero no tiene cuerpo (el cuerpo de la función es lo que va entre llaves `{` y `}`.
2. La función `Persona::Persona(int, int, int)` está declarada y definida pero el compilador no encuentra la definición. Tal vez la definición esté en otro archivo de código que por algún motivo no está siendo compilado.

#### Solución

Añade la definición de la función `Persona::Persona(int, int, int)` (constructor) a tu código; para hacerlo "*más claro*" yo la añadiría en la misma posición que la declaración, es decir antes de la función `Persona::asignAlt`:

```
Persona::Persona(int altura, int peso, int promedio) :
    alt(altura), pe(peso), prommd(promedio) {}

void Persona::asignAlt(int mAlt,int pAlt){
alt=(mAlt+pAlt)/2; }
void Persona::cPe(int mPe,int pPe,int cd){
pe=((mPe+pPe)/2)+cd/100; }
void Persona::promm(int prom){
prommd=prom/30; }
void Persona::prnt(){
cout<<"La altura de la persona es de: "<<alt<<"\nSu peso es de: "<<pe<<"\nY su ingreso diario es de: "<<prommd; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Persona::Persona(int, int , int)
{

}
```

Agrégale esta linea el problema es que no has agregado la declaración del constructor.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es con el constructor de tu clase Persona, ya que los constructores y destructores no llevan un **;** al final.

```
Persona{
    public:
        Persona(){}  // Contructor
        ~Persona(){} // Destructor
};
```

Comment: Estás mezclando churras con merinas. En la declaración de la clase (_la parte que tu comentas_) puede haber implementación de funciones o no. Si implementas en la declaración (_algo generalmente no recomendado_), entonces tu solución sí es aplicable. Sin embargo, si la implementación va por separado es imperativo finalizar las funciones con punto y coma para que la posterior implementación sea tomada como válida.

Comment: Como mencioné: Los constructores y destructores.

Comment: El ejemplo que pones únicamente es válido si la implementación se encuentra en la cabecera... si quieres mover la implementación a un `cpp` tienes que dejar la función (sea constructor, destructor o cualquier otra) acabando en punto y coma.